# Prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_1^2\frac{\sin(tx)}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Prove that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_1^2\frac{\sin(tx)}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx=0$$

I'm hoping there's some better way to go about this other than bounding the integral by $\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx$, because that integral seems to require two substitutions. Is there?

Comment: You might want to look up the Riemann---Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @JonasMeyer:  I don't quite see how the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma helps here, given that we have a finite integration range, not infinite as is necessary for a Fourier Transform and hence the Lemma to be invocable.  Any insights or next steps?

Comment: @David: There are formulations for bounded intervals; or just take the function to be zero outside this interval.

Comment: @davidg.stork The RLL does not require the limits to be unbounded.  In fact, the RLL for Fourier series, not transforms, has the integration on a closed bounded integral.

Comment: @Dr. MV.  OK.  Interesting.  So is the solution merely creating an $L_1$ function $1/(x^2 \sqrt{x-1})$ on the interval $1 \to 2$, looking at the real part of its Fourier Transform and invoking the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In fact, any $L^1$ function can be uniformly approximated in the $L^1$ norm by a smooth function with compact support.  Note that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}} \in L^1[1,2]$, or alternatively the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}&,1\le x\le 2\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$is clearly $L^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Dr. MV:  Yes... I understood your point before (as I tried to describe).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Pleased to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the proof
of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma
in [http://n.ethz.ch/~lukaswi/download/WS0506/MMP1/solution9-2.pdf](http://n.ethz.ch/%7Elukaswi/download/WS0506/MMP1/solution9-2.pdf),
in this case
the easiest proof would be
integration by parts
in the form

$\int_a^b f(x)\sin(tx)dx
=-\frac1{t}f(x)\cos(tx)\big|_a^b
-\frac1{t}\int_a^b f'(x)\cos(tx)dx
$.

In this case,
although the function is not bounded
(at $1$),
its integral is,
so this applies.

Comment: Marty, this approach doesn't quite work unfortunately.  Note that for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}$ is not defined at $x=a=1$ and the integral $\int_1^2 f'(x)\cos(tx)\,dx$ diverges.  So, we need to uniformly approximate (approximate in the $L^1$ norm) $f$ by a smooth function of compact support and then integrate by parts.

Comment: Oh, well. As a poem of mine starts: If I thought I knew what I was doing, I would just start doing something else.

Comment: You are a poet indeed.